# Change font of labels with @IBDesignable

Tags: ios, swift

This is a class that is supposed to change the font of a label dynamically, right in the Storyboard:

```
@IBDesignable class FlexibleLabel: UILabel {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Brandon Grotesque", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}
```

I assigned this class to some labels but I get this error:

> Failed to update auto layout status: The agent crashed.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try setting the font inside `awakeFromNib` method

Comment: @ZellB. Your solutoon works. Feel free to answer with your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method which is called after the view is fully initialized from nib is UIView's `awakeFromNib()` method. You can override and use it to modify view's or subviews properties

Answer (score 1):

To figure out why the agent crashed, select the `FlexibleLabel` instance in your storyboard and from the menu bar choose Editor > Debug Selected Views. If the problem is in your code, Xcode should put you in the debugger at the crash.

Xcode doesn't use `init(coder:)` to create views when editing a storyboard. It uses `init(frame:)`, then sets the properties of the view using KVC (key-value coding).